# How to stub/mock XMLBeans object for testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, xmlbeans, stubbing

I'm working with an application using Apache XMLBeans (interfaces for XML structure elements extending org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject, implementations for those interfaces extending org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.values.XmlComplexContentImpl)

I got following kind of functionality:

- An XML object is passed to a method with some data
- Based on this data, subcontent is generated for this XML object

  - using XML objects' addFoo() to add elements etc

Now I'd like to have a test for this functionality but I'm not sure what is the best way to have this XML object for testing (I'd like the stub/mock object to maintain the subtree state to be easily tested). Some options:

- I tried instantiating these FooImpl implementation objects but they require reference to org.apache.xmlbeans.SchemaType sType

  - Is there some way to instantiate these?
  - Giving null / mocked SchemaType ends up with NPE when something is added
- Generating a stub classes with the few needed methods would work but ends up with many (> 100) methods to generate
- Using Mockito works otherwise, but to have the xml tree structure state easily tested, I need to use doAnswer() etc

Some ideas?

br, Touko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found myself that the answer was pretty easy : The xmlbeans interfaces have factory classes for instantiating the beans, for example:

```
Address.Factory.newInstance()
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is not the answer you're looking but here it goes anyway:

## Don't mock types you don't control

References:

- Steve Freeman and Nat Price from [Growing Object Oriented Systems, Guided by Tests](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/)
- Steve Freeman blog post about this subject: http://stevef.truemesh.com/archives/000194.html
- Detailed experience from a developer: http://davesquared.net/2011/04/dont-mock-types-you-dont-own.html

A question for you: What are you trying to test? That Apache XML beans works as expected? Or are you writing an XML tool?

Comment: Good point. I'm trying to test my business functionality that creates a XML structure using XMLBeans. (So I'm expecting that XMLBeans works as expected)

Comment: I hope I don't sound unfriendly, but if your business logic cares about XML, then you can only be writing an XML related tool. If you're writing any other application it means that you've mixed your business logic with the glue code that connects your application to the external world and you might want to read about how to separate these two. A good reference is the [hexagonal architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture)

Comment: My use of "business functionality" wasn't so good. The particular functionality I'm testing is kind of "paging" for the generated XML document so it's at the edge of business logic and XML.